# Add spaces into string dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, substring

I want to put a "-" after every three numbers.
For example:

```
$number = 123456789;
```

I want to make it as `123-456-789`;

Can someone give me a help?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `preg_replace` with `/\d{3}/` and replace with `'$0-'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chunk_split()`:

```
$number = "123456789";
$phone = chunk_split($number,3,"-");
$phone = substr($phone, 0, -1);  // remove trailing hyphen
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string to array and glue it back using `str_split`

```
$string = "12345678645465665646346";
 $arr = str_split($string, 3);
 $output = implode("-", $arr);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will serve your wish :)

```
echo trim(chunk_split('123456789', 3, '-'),'-');
```

Comment: This will leave a trailing hyphen that has to be stripped off.

Answer (score 0):

Use word wrap with the following:

```
$orig = "123456789";
$str = wordwrap($orig, 3, "-\n" , true);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think that OP wants a new line after each split.

Answer (score 0):

look at this solution also no line breaks after "-"

```
$output = wordwrap($inputstring, 3, "-&nbsp" , true);
echo $output;
```